# Is there any reason for u_sprite_size to be (0,0)?

Tags: sprite-kit, glsl, shader, skspritenode, fragment-shader

I've been working to add a fragment shader to a SKSpriteNode of size (1024,768) on a screen with a size of (1024, 768), but the variables in the shader keep returning strange values. The u_sprite_size is always (0,0) and the v_tex_coord.x seems to be 0.1435 at one end of the sprite and .16075 at the other.

Is there any reason this should be happening?

Comment: I have tried a number of different things, but I also keep getting u_sprite_size = (0.0, 0.0) for some strange reason. This is both in OpenGL mode and Metal mode. What gives? I can attempt to query the SKSpriteNode width and height, but these values do not seem to be exactly pixel accurate.